# Java: Comparing XMLs using XMLUnit

Tags: java, xml, junit

I am trying to use XMLUnit 1.3 to compare two similar XML files. Basically every thing is same. file1 is a copy of file2.

But in File2 I have changed the order of some values/elements in one node.

**file1.xml**

```
<root> 
  <ent> 
   <value> 
     <string>ada,cmb</string>  
   </value>    
  </ent> 
</root>
```

**file2.xml**

```
<root> 
  <ent> 
   <value> 
     <string>cmb,ada</string>  
   </value>    
  </ent> 
</root>
```

In my case, thease two files **must be equal**. Is it possible to achieve this with XMLUnit ?

**My code**

```
public void testXml() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {  
    String refXmlPaht = "../test1.xml";
    String testXmlPaht = "../test2.xml";
    Document doc1 = TransformXML.convertXmlToDom(refXmlPaht);
    Document doc2 = TransformXML.convertXmlToDom(testXmlPaht);

    Diff myDiff = new Diff(doc1, doc2);
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true);
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);

    assertXMLEqual("pieces of XML are not similar ", myDiff, true);
    assertTrue("but are they identical? " + myDiff, myDiff.identical());
}
```

**XMLUnit response**

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: but are they identical? 

org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff
    [different] Expected text value 'ada,cmb' but was 'cmb,ada' - comparing <string ...>ada,cmb</string> at /root[1]/ent[1]/value[1]/string[1]/text()[1] to <string ...>cmb,ada</string> at /root[1]/ent[1]/value[1]/string[1]/text()[1]...
```

Thank you for help.

Best regards,

coban

Comment: XMLUnit compares the text content, so 'ada, cmb' will never be the same as 'cmb, ada'. Like 'trust' will never be same to 'strut'. Ordering counts here.

Comment: In order to achieve similarity, you could change your information design - putting two units of information in to one tag/element is not a good idea imho

Comment: I would like to achieve to ignore ordering. Is this possible?

Comment: @user432895. nice, so it can be done after all. much better than my wisenheimer approach (+1)

Answer (score 7):

You can create your own [`DifferenceListener`](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/DifferenceListener.html) which implements the following method:

```
int differenceFound(Difference difference);
```

This method will be called whenever a difference is detected and you can then perform some string checking on the contents of the control and test nodes to see if they mean the same to you. If they are, you can return a value of `RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL`, so that XMLUnit treats the nodes as being identical.

Take a look at the [user guide](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/ar01s03.html) for more information.