# Java API which can idenetify the difference between two XML files

Tags: java, xml

I have `xyz.xml` file  in a path.

```
<xml>
  <emp>
    <name>rahul</name>
  <emp>
</xml>
```

I have a  GUI from which I update the name rahul->rahul tripathi and click on save button and update the XML file.

Now updated XML file will be like --

```
<xml>
  <emp>
    <name>rahul tripathi</name>
  <emp>
</xml>
```

Now from GUI, I want to show the difference between previous and updated  data which is stored in XML.

I found out [a link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_diff.htm#ADXDK204), but regarding this there is no library.

Comment: If _all_ the other formatting remains the same, then any old diff tool might be enough for what you need (q.v. [this tool](https://www.diffchecker.com/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used XmlUnit - http://www.xmlunit.org/ for this and it works great. Can ignore many more things than just whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Go through [XmlUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/), with little bit of tweaking, could be the good solution.

Please explore [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141993/best-way-to-compare-2-xml-documents-in-java) as well.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998229/finding-differences-in-two-xml-files-using-xmlunit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350807/java-comparing-xmls-using-xmlunit).

Complete example [here](https://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/xml-comparison-tutorial-using-xmlunit/).